# Horizontal scrolling in section of UICollectionView in iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uicollectionview

I develop an app for online shop that should has some design features that I don't know how to implement. Lurking for it second day, but no profit. I suggest, that it should be the simple CV with some custom cells for different needs (banners, products).

Problem - design has scrollable horizontally content in each section and I see no simple way to implement it instead of writing custom flow layout.

I tried to make a tableView with collection view in its rows, but its not working correctly.

May be you know some examples of implementation of same thing in swift or a good way to make such feature without flow layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer mention link May be help you from this link:-   https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/